# Tensorflow argmax give false indizes

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow to train and use a small neural network (2d classification with two classes), but I have a really strange problem and fail to see what I am doing wrong:
When I plot  [the predictions vs the true labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwUqG.png) only for test batches for that the accuracy evals to 1., I clearly have some missclassified samples. It seems to me, that tf.argmax is responsible for the accuracy to mistakenly evaluate to 1, but obviously this can't really be the reason.
Anyways, I came to this conclusion by calculating the accuracy from the last layer output:

```
with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    plabel = tf.argmax(y, 1) # vector of predicted label, elem {0,1}^batch_size
    tlabel = tf.argmax(y_, 1) # similar vector of true labels
    correct_predictions = tf.cast(tf.equal(plabel, tlabel), tf.float32) 
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    batchx, batchy = generate_batch()
    predictions, acc = sess.run([y, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batchx, y_: batchy})
    mistakes = 0.
    for j in range(batch_size):
        if (predictions[j, 0] - predictions[j, 1])*(batchy[j, 0] - batchy[j, 1]) < 0:
            print("mistake: ", predictions[j], batchy[j])
            mistakes += 1./batch_size
    print("Acc = {} / {} = 1-m/b".format(acc, 1. - mistakes))
```

x and y_ are the input tensors, y is the last layer and the model is trained already.

It gives me the following output:

```
Acc = 1.0 / 0.86 = 1-m/b
```

These values should be the same.

The plot also indicates that the true accuracy is not 1., or the evaluated accuracy tensor does not belong to the same run as the predictions (y).

I found nothing that hints that tf.argmax really is the issue, and am quite desperate. So thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

It seems your accuracy function is correct since you didn't post whole your code, I would suggest you calculate accuracy inside the session, so each time you can print the content of predictions and true labels and trace the execution.

Get predictions like `predictions = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: batchx, y_: batchy})` then print predictions by `print predictions.eval()`, then use `plabel = tf.argmax(predictions, 1)`, again `print plabel.eval()`, also `print batchy` and `print (tf.argmax(batchy)).eval()`

Now you should know what's going wrong with each `print` statement.

Comment: I modified the code like this, and after removing all the debug prints that only printed what you would expect, this remained: `acc, predictions, corrects, p, t = sess.run([accuracy, y, correct_predictions, plabel, tlabel], feed_dict=f)`  -  `for j in range(batch_size): print("This should be 1: ", fdict[y_][j, t[j]])` - but sometimes it prints 0.

Comment: Okay it was only a typo, in my original code I used a wrong feed dict. Sorry and thanks

Answer (score 0):

For accuracy :

```
def evaluate(X_data, y_data):
    num_examples = len(X_data)
    total_accuracy = 0
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
        batch_x, batch_y = X_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE], y_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE]
        accuracy = sess.run(accuracy_operation, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        total_accuracy += (accuracy * len(batch_x))
    return total_accuracy / num_examples
```

for getting the prediction :

```
prediction = sess.run(tf.argmax(logits, 1), feed_dict={x: train_data})
```